# MongoEngine: A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef or documents when defining document_type as str

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

In one MongoEngine model I'm using a reference field, when I use

```
schedule =  ReferenceField('Schedule',required=True)
```

and attempt to insert the document

```
#my_schedule being a 'Schedule' object that has been created and saved successfully
record.schedule = my_schedule
record.save()
```

I get

```
ValidationError: ValidationError (Calling:None) (A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef or documents: ['schedule'])
```

However if I change the field definition to

```
schedule =  ReferenceField(path.to.Schedule,required=True)
```

(I.E. directly reference the Schedule model)

The document can be saved successfully. How can I avoid this error?

Full defenition of the Schedule model

```
class Schedule(Document):
    
    uid =       StringField(required=True)
    
    start =     DateTimeField(required=True)
    end =       DateTimeField(required=True)
    
    days =      ListField(required=True)
    
    toc =       StringField(required=False)
    
    meta = {
        'indexes':['uid']
    }
```

And for Calling

```
class Calling(Document):
    """
    Calling Point
    """
    
    schedule =  ReferenceField('Schedule',required=True)
    
    tiploc =    StringField(required=True)
    calling =   ListField(StringField(required=True))
    
    arrive =    IntField(required=False)
    depart =    IntField(required=False)
    
    meta = {
        'indexes':[('schedule','calling','tiploc','depart'),('schedule','tiploc')]
    }
```

Python 2.7, MongoEngine 0.8.2, PyMongo 2.5.2

## Update

As requested; Output of `_document_registry`

```
{'Calling': <class 'models.calling.Calling'>,
 'Schedule': <class 'models.schedule.Schedule'>,
 'Station': <class 'models.station.Station'>,
 'Stop': <class 'models.stop.Stop'>,
 'Train': <class 'models.train.Train'>,
 'Update': <class 'models.update.Update'>}
```

Folder layout;

```
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── models
│   └── views
└── tasks
```

app/models controls all my models, this particular error is happening in tasks/update.py (imports a data file into Mongo, run as a cron-job). app/ is appended to the system path when the app loads, if that makes a difference.

in app/models I have one file per model, so app/models/schedule.py contains Schedule etc.

And yes, you are correct in that I have solved the problem by referencing the object directly, however doing that creates a circular dependency problem between calling.py and schedule.py, while I could move Calling and Schedule models to the same file I don't want to because I'm a stubborn programmer and like my one-model-per-file rule despite it making no real difference =)

## Update 2

Adding

```
print type(my_schedule), schd, type(Schedule)
```

gives me

```
<class 'app.models.schedule.Schedule'> Schedule object <class 'mongoengine.base.metaclasses.TopLevelDocumentMetaclass'>
```

Comment: Interesting - you can fix it by including the class as you have, rather than the string name of the class :)

Otherwise, what directory layout are you using for your Document definitions and are you duplicating names?

Comment: Also could you paste the contents of the document registry: mongoengine.common._document_registry

Comment: @Ross Updated (extra text for character limit etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The definitions look fine, I have a feeling its an import error being masked by the validation error message.

When using `Calling` you **have** to have imported `Schedule` somewhere in your code, so that it exists in the document class repository at the time.  Does tasks/update.py import both Calling and Schedule models?

Comment: Yes, tasks/update.py imports `from app.models import Update, Station, Schedule, Calling`. And further up the code the script that runs update.py does `from app.models import *`.

Comment: I've just created a dummy project with the same layout and can't reproduce.  Can you print type(my_schedule)

Comment: I cant reproduce - if you can provide a repo case I'll look into it.